# Object Literals and Prototypal Inheritance?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

In javascript, I have an object literal:

```
var objA = {
  doStuff: function() {
    // do objA stuff
  }
}
```

I extend objA, and override the doStuff method:

```
var objB = _.extend(objA, {
  doStuff: function() {
    // do objB stuff
  }
});
```

However, now when objB.doStuff() is called only objB stuff gets done.

I would like for both objA and objB stuff to be done.  I tried the following:

```
var objB = _.extend(objA, {
  doStuff: function() {
    this.prototype.doStuff.call(this, arguments);
    // do objB stuff
  }
});
objB.__proto__ = objA;
```

However this doesn't work.  I guess I don't understand how prototypal inheritance works when extending  object literals.  So, what is the right way to do this?

Comment: For a plain object, its `[[Prototype]]` is *Object.prototype*, so that's where you need to put inherited methods. Note that it's considered bad form to modify the built–in *Object.prototype* object, you should create your own constructor and modify its *prototype*.

Comment: What do you mean by "*only objB stuff gets done*"? Notice that in your example `objB === objA`!

Comment: @Bergi OP is expecting `objB.doStuff()` to also call the "parent method" on `objA`, which of course makes no sense, because `_.extend` doesn't touch prototypes, nor does JavaScript have `super` (yet).

Comment: You're treating a plain `object` like a `class`. It does not, and should not, work the way you're asking.

Comment: You may be interested in patterns for inheritance and overriding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like for both objA and objB stuff to be done.

You have to call the method of `objA` explicitly:

```
var objB = _.extend({}, objA, {
  doStuff: function() {
    objA.doStuff.apply(this, arguments);
    // do objB stuff
  }
}, objA);
```

Note that I'm adding an empty object as first argument, so that first `objA`'s properties are merged and then yours. For more info about how `_.extend` works, see the [documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#extend).

> Object Literals and Prototypal Inheritance?

Object literals currently don't provide a way to set the prototype. You can create an empty object with a specific prototype with [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) and then merge other properties into it:

```
var objB = Object.create(objA);
// `merge` is a fictional function that copies properties from object to another
merge(objB, {
   doStuff: function() { ... }
});
```

You can still only call `objA`'s method by explicitly referencing it.

---

*Note: This section probably has to be revised after ES6 is finalized and implement.*

In **ES6** you will probably be able to set the prototype [via the `__proto__` property name](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-__proto__-property-names-in-object-initializers):

```
var objB = {
  __proto__: objA,
  doStuff: function() { }
};
```

or via [`Object.setPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf):

```
var objB = {...};
Object.setPrototypeOf(objB, objA);
```

Then you should be able to call `objA`s method via the `super` keyword:

```
var objB = {
  __proto__: objA,
  doStuff: function() {
    super.doStuff();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Unserscore's [`_.extend`](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) function doesn't return a new object.

It returns the same object extended, with the new properties. So, your `objA` has the new `doStuff` function.

Instead, you may want to use [`_.clone`](http://underscorejs.org/#clone) and then rewrite `doStuff` on `objB`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing in your example isn't actually inheritance, but simply creation and modification. To achieve inheritance in Javascript, it's not actually an OBJECT that you are extending, per se. It's a function. An object doesn't provide direct access to its prototype, a function does. So what you're after is likely something more like:

```js
function ObjA() {
    return this;
}
ObjA.prototype.doStuff = function() {
    // do objA stuff
};

function ObjB() {
    return this;
}
ObjB.prototype = new ObjA();
ObjB.prototype.doStuff = function() {
    ObjA.prototype.doStuff.apply(this, arguments);
    // do objB stuff
}

var objA = new ObjA(),
    objB = new ObjB();
```

Comment: *"An object has no prototype"* Of course it does, every object has a prototype (well, `Object.prototype` doesn't). Don't confuse this with the `prototype` properties of a function.

Comment: Yes, I believe my wording here is misleading. Just because an object doesn't provide direct access to the prototype by which it was created, doesn't mean that it isn't there.

Comment: Yep, every object has an internal `[[Prototype]]` property. You can get the prototype via `Object.getPrototypeOf`.